# Any "Image Sprite" Class/Libraries/Helpers for Flash AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3

Is there AS3 classes/libaries for Flash that, in the traditional meaning of 'Sprite', render only a certain part of one image?

Short of making my own, I imagine some kind of convience method has been done before. But 'Sprite' meaning `Sprite` in ActionScript makes it impossible to Google etc.

Many thanks,
Ross

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See scrollRect property, that should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

there was the animatedbitmap class by hexagon star, while the website looks like it's gone, drawlogic still has some info on it + the download link

http://drawlogic.com/2007/09/22/as3-animated-bitmap-class/

http://files.hexagonstar.com/classes/as3/animatedbitmap.zip

*edit*

looks like there is something here -> 
http://blog.hexagonstar.com/animatedbitmapclass/